# How to password protect one page the vue way?

Tags: vue.js, password-protection, nuxt.js

I am building a website with nuxtjs and was wondering if I could password protect only one webpage with vuejs and not vanilla javascript.

Is this possible? if so! how?

The goal is to show the webpage to only those that i granted the password to, but the rest of the website is public to all, I am not really looking for a user authentication system, just a password protected one page!

Comment: Google `.htaccess`. Password protection cannot by any means be done in the frontend alone. Vue will not help you here.

Comment: This is an SPA, correct? If so, then you can't really guarantee that a user won't just force the page to display by modifying the page state in their browser. A user could also simply view the page source or sift through the browser's element inspector to see what the page should look like and how it functions. If you want a secured webpage, then you'll need to either maintain a separate page and use some authentication mechanism like `.htpasswd`, or you'll need to look into solutions involving an encrypted page that can be decrypted using a strong password.

Comment: @B.Fleming yea thank you, i figured after connexo ‘s comment that any implementation wouldn’t be legit, I’m going to try the htaccess route

Answer (score 0):

Why not make an ajax call to a server ? a simple php function would return true or false if the password you had defined is correct.

Comment: can you provide an example?